# Ask for Exclusive lock while holding Shared lock - SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, concurrency, transactions, locking

What happens when a transaction is holding a shared lock on some resource and then it asks for an exclusive one on the same resource? Does it first unlock its shared lock and then wait for the exclusive one? Or does it hold its shared lock until it can obtain the exclusive one on that resource? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It holds its shared lock until it gets an exclusive one.

If this is not granted immediately then the status shown for this pending lock request in the DMVs is `CONVERT`